# Rendering a Glyph to a bitmap image in C++ using SFML

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, bitmap, sfml, glyph

I want to generate a bitmap image of a glyph so that I can compare it to pixel values of unknown letters in another image.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, my project is in C++ and I'm using SFML. I can load in a font from a ttf file fine, and I tried to do something like:

```
sf::Font myFont;
myFont.loadFromFile("Path\\arial.ttf");

sf::Texture myTexture = myFont.getTexture(48);
sf::Image textureImage = myTexture.copyToImage();

sf::Glyph myGlyph = myFont.getGlyph(65, 12, false); // get the 'A' glyph

sf::Image glyphImage;
glyphImage.create(myGlyph.bounds.width, myGlyph.bounds.height, sf::Color::White);
glyphImage.copy(textureImage, 0, 0, myGlyph.textureRect);
```

I believe this doesn't work because I am just creating an image from the part of the texture where the glyph is located, rather than the pixel values of the glyph itself.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
unsigned int size = 20;
sf::Glyph glyph = font.getGlyph('A', size, false);
sf::Texture bitmap = font.getTexture(size);

sf::Image image;
image.create(glyph.bounds.width, glyph.bounds.height);
image.copy(bitmap.copyToImage(), 0, 0, glyph.textureRect);
```

Note that in this sample the character size is the same when `getGlyph` and `getTexture` are called, which was not the case in your code above.

Also, instead of magic number like `65` use `'A'` for readability.

Comment: Great, that worked for me :) It was the difference in character size that caused the failure. Thanks for your help!